# Schedule Twilio call

Tags: python, twilio

I currently am able to make a call using the Twilio API with the following python code:

```
#Download the library from twilio.com/docs/libraries
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Get these credentials from http://twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "myaccountsid"
auth_token = "myauthtoken"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# Make the call
call = client.calls.create(to="+12345789123",  # Any phone number
                           from_="+12345789123", # Must be a valid Twilio number
                           url="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient")
print call.sid
```

Now I want to schedule this code to be executed at a particular time. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* way? If you're running a Unix-like OS, the easiest way is with [`at`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html):

```
$ echo "python script.py" | at 1400
```

The command above executes `script.py` at 2 p.m. system time. (Note: Some OSs, such as OS X, disable `atrun` execution by default; you may need to enable it. See `$ man atrun` for help.)

This is a very primitive solution. Alternatives include using your OS's `init` functionality (including via [`cron`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)) or constructing a daemon.

Comment: I tried to use the following chrontab 25 16 18 1 * /Users/myusername/Documents/makecall.py however this doesn't work. Any idea why? I feel like it might be because I have to type source bin/activate before I'm able to run the script

Comment: @Apollo Is the script an executable? (If not, you need the Python interpreter before the path.) Does the user who's `cron` your modifying have the right permissions? Can you execute the same exact command from the shell? If you're using virtualenv, you need to set your Python interpreter to the `{path}/venv/bin/python`.

Comment: Yes, I've run chmod +x on makecall.py, so that once I type source bin/activate then I can run it with ./makecall.py. And yes, I'm using virtualenv. I'm not quite sure what you mean by changing the path of the Python interpreter.